# Regex to convert this String

Tags: java, regex, string

How can I convert this String `AB23-01-0001` to `AB23010001`( replacing the "-" with "") and `AB230001` (removing the middle part) using regex in Java, right row I'm using `replace` for the first case and `substring`  and appending them into a SB for the second case. Just wanted to know how to achieve it using REGEX.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use build-in method to remove both parts at once with RegEx:

```
String value = "AB23-01-0001";
value = value.replaceAll("-[\\d\\w]+-", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("-[^-]*-");
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher("AB23-01-0001");
System.out.println(m1.replaceAll(""));
```

To [test it](http://goo.gl/T4JyZW)

A replacement to the patter is `Pattern.compile("-[\\d\\w]+-")`

Comment: Thanks let me try it out. Any idea for the second case?

Comment: @xtreme Both the patterns work to remove the dash and the content between them

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the method built into the String class?

```
String newString = "AB23-01-0001".replaceAll("[-]", "");
```

Note the use of `[]` - a regex string, since you are just replacing a `-`, you can omit them.

Comment: Don't need `[]` character class

Comment: Very true, wanted to note the fact that it will take a RegEx like asked :p

Comment: @MattClark Thank you, but the application that I'm using for the data manipulation has an inbuilt Regex transformer that would take the regex inputs. thats why interested in REGEX

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "AB23-01-0001"
happy = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)